# JavaScript arguments keyword and multiple arguments ...args

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some issues with my code. Here I will show two versions of my code but one of them is not working.

This code using the `arguments` keyword is not working:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = {
    'one':'b',
    'two':'c',
    'three':'d'
  }
  function func(){
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
      $('.a').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass(data[arguments[i]])){
          $(this).css('background','red')
        }
      })
    }
  }
  func('one','two')
})
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  pading:0;
  height:100vh;
}
.a{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:green;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a c"></div>
```

However when I use a rest parameter, `...val`, everything works perfectly:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = {
    'one': 'b',
    'two': 'c',
    'three': 'd'
  }

  function func(...val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      $('.a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass(data[val[i]])) {
          $(this).css('background', 'red')
        }
      })
    }
  }
  func('one', 'two')
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  pading: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.a {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a c"></div>
```

How do I make this code work perfectly without using  `...val` and by using only the `arguments` keyword?

Comment: The `arguments` object gets a new value on *every* function call, including the function passed to `.each()`.  The value of `arguments` inside there is not the same as the value outside. If you used a `=>` function for the `.each()` callback, it would work, because such functions work differently in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a local var inside func():

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var data = {
        'one':'b',
        'two':'c',
        'three':'d'
      }
      function func(){
        for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
          var key = arguments[i]
          $('.a').each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass(data[key])){
              $(this).css('background','red')
            }
          })
        }
      }
      func('one','two')
    })
```

In the original posted form, the nested anonymous function was referring to its own **arguments**, but the intent (as I interpreted it) was to refer to the **arguments** of the call to func() instead.  As it was pointed out by others, that is not possible since the **arguments** keyword is always local to the current function.  Therefore by adding a var to the closure (inside func() but outside of the nested anonomous function) you can refer to that "copy" of the data in the outer **arguments** instead when inside the nested function.

Answer (score 3):

This is because 'arguments' is a reserved keyword in Javascript. It's context will change when you call it inside other function inside the `.each()`. It is not just like any other variable that will be passed inside as it is.

If you want to achieve that, you should use arrow functions.
[Arrow functions in JS](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/)
Hope that the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There are two more possible ways to do this in addition to your way:

- Use an arrow function so that the scope of arguments is still linked to the outer 
  function.
- If you want to keep the function, you can pass the value every time as a parameter, but that's just a wastage of computational power.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use input parameter (`...val` in your case).
Every time you call your method you pass a new parameter in it.

Comment: according to my question i actually do not wanna use ...val i was asking for some alternatives